# how to get uper-left and lower-right x y position of screen in openLayers map?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

My problem is that when my map is loaded at that time I want to get X and Y cordinates of all four corners of screen as per resolution. My code:

```js
map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv", {
  controls: [new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
    new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar()
  ],
  numZoomLevels: 10
});

map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OpenCycleMap"));
epsg4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
epsg900913 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(72.58, 23.03).transform(epsg4326, epsg900913);
console.log(lonLat);
var zoom = 15;

var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
map.addLayer(markers);
map.events.register("click", map, function (e) {
  var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy);
  alert(lonlat);
});
markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat));
var polygonLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Polygon Layer");

map.addLayer(polygonLayer);
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
map.setCenter(lonLat, zoom);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to post a fiddle when you can. Assuming you're using OpenLayers v2.

If you meant to ask how to get the corners of the viewport, try:

`map.getViewport().getClientRects()[0]`

If you meant the extent of the map in coordinates:

`map.getExtent()`